# Using lambda function node-js I want to establish two different database engine (One is SQL serve and other is Postgres)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sql-server-ce

Want to connect two different database engines (i.e Postgres and Mssql) using nodeJS in lambda script.

```
   exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      try {
        sql.connect(config, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          callback(err);
        } else {
          const req = new sql.Request();
          req.query("select top 10 * from queue", async (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
              callback(error);
            } else { 
                const { Client } = require('pg');
                const client = new Client();
                await client.connect();
                var res = await client.query("select * from nq");
                var notificationData = res.rows;
                console.log(notificationData);


              console.log(params);*/


                sql.close();
                callback(null, result.recordset);
            }
          });
        }
      });

      sql.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
      });
      } catch (e) {
         console.log(e);
         console.error(e);
         sql.close();
      }
    };
```

Want to retrieve data from SQL server database and based on the ID want to retrieve similar data from Postgres Database from the same lambda script function.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Have to establish two databases in single lambda function ?